# Why is my char printing as a number instead of a character?

Tags: java, char, int

As per the Java ternary operator `expression ? statement1 : statement2`,
if `expression` is true then `statement1` will be executed, if `expression` is false then `statement2` will be executed.

But when I run:

```
// some unnecessary codes not displaying
char y = 'y';
int i = 0;
System.out.print(false ? i : y);
```

I am expecting it to print `y` but its printing `121`, why?

**EDIT** 
As per the manouti answer, the compiler interprets as `int`, but if that is the case then why I am seeing dead code at `i`?

If I do `System.out.print(false ? 0 : x);` then I am getting `y`, so why in this case doesn't the compiler interpret as `int`?

Comment: the compiler should really just reject these cases - it's not easy for human programmers to understand all the little details. When a compiler outsmarts the programmer, there'll be trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that the value printed is based on the type that the conditional expression evaluates to.

So really your question boils down to, why does the type of the conditional expression differ between

```
char y = 'y';
int i = 0;
System.out.print(false ? i : y); // prints 121
```

and

```
char y = 'y';
System.out.print(false ? 0 : y); // prints y
```

To answer that, we'll need to take a look at [section §15.25 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

There are three types of conditional expression in Java:

- Boolean Conditional Expressions
- Numeric Conditional Expressions
- Reference Conditional Expressions

Since both `int` and `char` are convertible to a numeric type, the expression is an example of a **numeric conditional expression** according to this rule:

> If both the second and the third operand expressions are numeric expressions, the conditional expression is a numeric conditional expression.
>
> For the purpose of classifying a conditional, the following expressions are numeric expressions:
>
> - An expression of a standalone form (§15.2) with a type that is convertible to a numeric type (§4.2, §5.1.8).

Given that, the rule for determining the type of the entire expression is given as follows:

> **15.25.2. Numeric Conditional Expressions**
>
> Numeric conditional expressions are standalone expressions (§15.2).
>
> The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - If the second and third operands have the same type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.
> - If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is short.
> - If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the operands is of type T, where T is Byte, Short, or Character, and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in the type U which is the result of applying unboxing conversion to T, then the type of the conditional expression is U.
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.
>
> <sub>Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).</sub>

Notice that the fourth rule exactly describes the second example; the second operand is constant of type `int` (`0`) and the third is a `char`, so the conditional expression will evaluate to `char`.  This will cause the compiler to use the `print(char)` method, which will print `y`.

However when you instead pass in a *variable* instead of a *constant*, you fall down to the last rule which says that "...the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands."

If you take a look at [section §5.6.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), it describes the rules for type promotion as follows:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

By following these rules, the type of the expression will be `int`, and so the compiler will use the `print(int)` method, which will print `121` (the ascii value of `y`).

Comment: Been looking for this in the JLS +1

Comment: @manouti what really surprised me is that it specifies that the constant has to be an `int` to auto-evaluate to the type of the other operand, so `print(false ? 0L : y)` falls through to binary numeric promotion just like for using a variable, and prints `121` again.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that in Java, integer literals can automatically be assigned to more specific primitive variables like `short` when their values fit, e.g. `short c = 0;` works without a cast, but `short c = 0L;` does not.

Answer (score 10):

`121` is the integer representation of the character `y`. Since you provided `i` as part of the expression, the compiler interprets it as a call to `System.out.print(int)` instead of `System.out.print(char)`.

Note that changing to `System.out.print(false ? (char)i : y);` prints `y`.

Comment: but why ?In my eclipse it shows dead code at i so this means i is not reachable and even then why it interprets as int

Comment: @rocking you can always treat a char as an int, but not always an int as a char (I think, not a Java expert). Since the type of the expression must be constant, I imagine this is why it's inferred to int.

Comment: @rocking you have dead code because you are using a constant `boolean` in the ternary operator as condition. The Java compiler is able to infer, that the `true` case is never entered and therefore is unreachable.

Comment: @OMGtechy *since the type of the expression must be constant* That is unnecessary complicated. Each expression in Java has one type and one type only. So does the ternary operator. What is happening is an (automatic) upcast from `char` to `int` so the ternary operator has a proper defined type (in this case: `int`).

Comment: implicit conversion chain:
`byte -> short -> int -> long`

Answer (score 1):

121 is ASCII code for **y** and as you have declared **i** as an integer, the compiler interprets **y** as int variable too. Thus printing an ASCII value for **y**. Writing **System.out.print(false ? (char)i : y)** will print **y**.